# Adding Jquery To my Site

Tags: jquery, post

Hello friend I am trying to make a word press blog but i need to insert j query directly on my post.As default there is only html inserting tab is there any way i can insert j query to my post.It will be really help full if you can give me a answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this (it is html):
`<script type="text/javascript" src="put jQuery link here">
</script>`

I'm sure wordpress has a tool for this though. Or an editor has the feature. Adding it the way I provide should work but seems not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the question is not elaborate. because you can create a wordpress blog without any coding skills. There is 2 things that should work when ur working with jquery. 1. create wordpress template 2. create a plugin. then you can insert all the things that you want to.